# Minification safe directive with link attribute in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is very handly directive at to format date in ng-model with HTML input [here](https://codepen.io/giovani_araujo/pen/jPGXNo).

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.firstDate = new Date();
    $scope.secondDate = "2014-02-20";
}).directive('date', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            var dateFormat = attrs['date'] || 'yyyy-MM-dd';

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, dateFormat);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I tried to use same for my project,but the problem is that is fails to work when javascript file is minified. It logs an error [$injector:unpr] ...../$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20dateDirective. 
I tried to minify using [this](https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/)
Please guide me on how to minify this directive.

Comment: See this plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mJJSC7KW7O6V7V4ck1w5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you don't use injection a.e `$inject`.

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope){/* ... */}]);
.directive('date', ['dateFilter', function (dateFilter) {/* ... */}]);
```

So your directive (and controller) will look like:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.firstDate = new Date();
    $scope.secondDate = "2014-02-20";
}]).directive('date', ['dateFilter', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            var dateFormat = attrs['date'] || 'yyyy-MM-dd';

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, dateFormat);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: can you please help with a small example. I would appreciate it.